# Postgres CASE and Range to give a scaled score

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
table: move_score_total
ID | Move_score_total
1  | 5.7865
2 .| 11.543
3 .| 14.29734
```

and so on....
I'd like to run a query that delivers this (don't care about column order):

```
table: move_score_total
ID | scaled_score | Move_score_total
1  | 200          |5.7865
2 .| 80           |11.543
3 .| 20           |14.29734
```

I am new to case and ranges, but I thought this query might be close. Am I? Or am I way off as the error I get is:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "numrange"
LINE 3: ...  WHEN move_score_total.move_score_total::numeric numrange[0...


SELECT move_score_total."ID", 
CASE move_score_total.move_score_total
   WHEN move_score_total.move_score_total numrange[0,8) THEN 200
   WHEN move_score_total.move_score_total numrange[8,10) THEN 100
   WHEN move_score_total.move_score_total numrange[10,12) THEN 80                                    
   WHEN move_score_total.move_score_total numrange[12,14) THEN 40    
   WHEN move_score_total.move_score_total numrange[14,16) THEN 20 
   WHEN move_score_total.move_score_total numrange[16,18) THEN 10 
   WHEN move_score_total.move_score_total numrange[18,20) THEN 1                                         
ELSE NULL
END AS scaled_score
FROM move_score_total;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would replace the `case` with this outer join:

```
select "ID", scaled_score
from
    move_score_total
    left outer join (values
        (numrange (0,8), 200),
        (numrange (8,10), 100),
        (numrange (10,12), 80),
        (numrange (12,14), 40),
        (numrange (14,16), 20),
        (numrange (16,18), 10),
        (numrange (18,20), 1)
    ) s (r, scaled_score) on move_score_total <@ r
```

Comment: THANK YOU! As I said, I'm new to some of this, so can you point me to documentation or explain what  s, r and <@ represent on the last line? I think I get the rest :)